# Is there any restriction on job_name length in dbms_scheduler.create_job call. In my case if job_name length is more than 30 then error is coming

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any restriction on job_name length in dbms_scheduler.create_job call. In my case if job_name length is more than 30 then error is coming.

Comment: Question would be **much** better if we knew *what* error you're receiving.

Comment: ...and what version of Oracle you have.

Answer (score 3):

The `dbms_schedule` indicates this is oracle - in which case yes, there is a limit of 30 characters on object names within the database.

Docs : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Comment: Thanks for the info and link.

Comment: .. but, if you upgrade to 12.2, then the limit is increased to 128 bytes. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA

Comment: @APC you get 128-byte identifiers out of the box from 12.2, unless [`COMPATIBLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/COMPATIBLE.html) is set to an earlier release. It's `VARCHAR2` columns that can be extended via the [`MAX_STRING_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) parameter.